# Picture as background in Xamarin Forms is not displayed

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use a picture as background in my Xamarin Forms Android app. That image is stored in drawable folder. The image is not displayed when I debug the app on my smartphone. Below is the code. Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinTest"
             x:Class="XamarinTest.MainPage"
             BackgroundImage = "BGImage.jpeg">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the build action property of the image?

Comment: Halo haldo, the property is embedded resource. Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, that's fine.  What is the file name?  Does it contain any `-` dash/hyphen characters?  If it does contain `-` try replacing with `_` and see if that works.

Comment: Helo haldo the name is without any - or other characters. In the Android Emulator the Image is displayed but in my smartphone not

Comment: Could you try `Android resource` instead of `Embedded resource`? Is this android or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just store it in the folder but not add it in the project.

you should right click the resource->drawable folder -->add-->add file to add the image file .

Answer (score 0):

Check where do you store your images:

For Android, iOS - Resource Folder;

For Windows Phone, Win/UWP - Assets folder;

Also check "Build action" (it should be `AndroidResource` for Android, `BundleResource` for iOS) and additionally (if still not showing) "Copy To Ouput Directory" should be "Copy if newer".
[image]